# Chrome Extension: Inject content_scripts into blob URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script, bloburls

### Problem Setup

This example html:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            let blob = new Blob(["<html>Blob content!</html>"], {type: 'text/html'});
            let blobUrl= URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.location.href = blobUrl;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Initial Page
    </body>
</html>
```

Produces a new html page with the content: `<html>Blob content!</html>`.

The page URL is: blob:null/c608e557-cacb-4bec-bce2-1f68c6315415

I have a chrome extension with the `manifest.json` looking something like this:

```json
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "match_origin_as_fallback": true,
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "js": ["getPage.js"],
    "all_frames": true
}]
```

### Question

Why does the content_script getPage.js not get injected into the blob URL?

Comment: Could it be because <all_urls> doesn't match blob: ?

Comment: This may be a relevant source for the problem: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#injecting-in-related-frames

Comment: Your code works for me, the content script is injected, when html is served from localhost. When file:// URL is used it doesn't work which may be considered a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Which manifest version are you using? Does it work with manifest version 2?

Comment: I tested with MV3. I don't have the files anymore.